# AES using mathematical notation

Tags: algorithm, encryption, aes, tripledes

I was wondering if AES can be represented using mathematical notation, if so, how?

During research I came across mathematical notation for triple DES but wasn't able to find one for AES.

Encryption

```
ciphertext = EK3(DK2(EK1(plaintext)))
```

Decryption

```
plaintext = DK1(EK2(DK3(ciphertext)))
```

Comment: What about ciphertext = AESenc(plaintext, key)?

Comment: But that doesn't reflect rounds in AES i.e., how would you know by looking at that how many rounds you have to compute - i might be wrong, correct me if i am :)

Comment: Your triple DES formula also does not reflect that DES has rounds nor that it is a Feistel network.

Comment: aw, your right!,

Comment: Would there be any way to show in more details of the algorithm like with triple des, we can show the use of 3 keys

Comment: How do you know the rounds with `EK3(DK2(EK1(plaintext)))`? Hint, you don't. Also AES has a different number of rounds for different key lengths.

Comment: Yes, your correct !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might be a better fit for cryptography.se

Answer (score 2):

`EK3(DK2(EK1(plaintext)))`

That is the definition of triple DES (3DES) not DES, that is encrypt plaintext with DES as  with key 1, decrypt that result with key 2, encrypt that result with key 3

3DES or triple DES encrypts three time with DES.

So AES would be: `Ek(plaintext)` with AES. (the "k" should be a subscript)

For more mathematical notations and cryptography in general see [*Handbook of Applied Cryptography*](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/index.html) by Alfred J. Menezes, Paul C. van Oorschot and Scott A. Vanstone, for free download.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the message - I did say Triple DES :)

Comment: So decryption would be EK(ciphertext)

Comment: I meant to write DK(ciphertext)

Comment: @Jackie See updated answer for a link to the Handbook of Applied Cryptography.